# Expand all + Collapse all in Azure App Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-app-configuration

There's **"Expand all"** and **"Collapse all"** in the UI functionality of App Configuration but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I kind of hoped it would group configurations by some separator but apparently that's not what it's for and it's not documented anywhere.

Has anyone figured out what does it do?

[image: App configuration explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - it collapses a single key with multiple values and different labels.

[image]